# `withLatestFrom` - throw error on implementing with observable

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to integrate `ngrx` caching, using `rxjs` `withLatestFrom` operator. But getting an error as:

```
You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.
You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Anyone correct my code please?

here is my code :

```js
@Effect()
EffLoadCourse = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(LoadCourse.TYPE),
  withLatestFrom(
    this.store.pipe(select(subscribes.getCourses)), //getting it from store
    (action: LoadCourse, courses: ModelCourse[]) => {
      // console.log('action is ', action, 'courses is', courses)
      return courses;
    }
  ),
  mergeMap((courses: ModelCourse[]) => {

    if (courses) { //if courses available just return it
      map((courses: ModelCourse[]) => (new LoadCourseSuccess(courses))),
        catchError(err => of(new LoadCourseFail(err)))
      return;
    }
    //only return on courses unavailability
    return this.courseService.getCourse().pipe(
      map((courses: ModelCourse[]) => (new LoadCourseSuccess(courses))),
      catchError(err => of(new LoadCourseFail(err)))
    )
  })
)
```

Comment: pls show also your selector "getCourses" and how you defined your state

Comment: inside `mergeMap` you're not returning anything when `!courses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(courses){ //if courses available just return it
                    map((courses:ModelCourse[]) => (new LoadCourseSuccess(courses))),
                    catchError(err => of(new LoadCourseFail(err)))
                    return;
                }
```

You are not returning an action, just a `void`